# Is it possible to show a code coverage badge in bitbucket repositories?

Tags: bitbucket

In github it is possible to show a code coverage button. Is this possible in bitbucket as well?

https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges

**Attempts**

This site was found https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12797/provide-project-status-build-status-badges

Navigating to `https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>/addon/pipelines/home#!/badge/branch/<master>?svg=true` returns a dead link

Comment: If bitbucket supports links in Readme markdown, yes... I don't get the point of this question and it feels more directed to bitbucket support at all... Github.com  doesn't do code coverage, it's the coverage service duty to provide the badge image... Github.com just give links to the providers documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly show a code coverage badge in a bitbucket repository, but it would have to be from an external source like jenkins, codeclimate, etc.

According to your link, if you are using pipelines they now show a code coverage badge on the [project overview page](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12797/provide-project-status-build-status-badges#comment-34438504). If you want to add that to your README or display it somewhere external, that functionality has not been implemented.

Comment: Is this answer still valid?